# Django 1.6 templates Is it possible to wrap the {% url %} so it can take ** arguements? How?

Tags: python, django

The Django's built-in tag `url` tag now works like:

```
{% url 'path.to.some_view' arg1=v1 arg2=v2 %}
```

I want to write a `super_url` tag which works like:

```
kwargs={'arg1':v1,'arg2':v2,}
{% super_url 'path.to.some_view' **kwargs %}
```

or take a dictionary as its only arguments:

```
{% super_url 'path.to.some_view' kwargs %}
```

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass the [`url` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) a dictionary in the template and you should try to avoid performing any sort of login in the template anyway (unpacking dictionaries etc.).

Instead, you could [write your own custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) that does this for you using [the `reverse` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse). Something like (untested):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def kwargy_url(context, view_str, kwargs):
    ...
    return reverse(view_str, kwargs=kwargs)

# {% kwargy_url 'myapp.views.myview' kwarg_var %}
```